# Mahout: where can I find the java class executed by a bash shell script?

Tags: java, bash, shell, mahout

I'm tring to write a java program using some functions from Mahout. I know that I can execute some Mahout functions with command line but I also want to know where I can find those functions in the .java files.

https://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/generating-eigenfaces-with-mahout-svd-to-recognize-person-faces/

It seems like I can execute a java class with this command: $ mahout cleansvd -ci covariance.seq -ei output -o output2

So I checked the bash file and found this:
exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $MAHOUT_OPTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $CLASS "$@"

However I cannot find any definition or assignment of $CLASS, and I don't know where the "cleansvd" class is.

Also, I can execute this command to perform a Singular Value Decomposition with 5 arguments:
$ mahout svd --input covariance.seq --numRows 150 --numCols 150 --rank 50 --output output
And I did find class SingularValueDecomposition in the source file, which takes only one argument and cannot reduce rank.

I really want to know what happened and how shell scripts locate java classes.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, that's a very old blog post.

I wrote this one to use with "new mahout".

https://rawkintrevo.org/2016/11/10/deep-magic-volume-3-eigenfaces/

It uses Scala, not Java, but the code is very simple and straight forward. You could easily make a jar and import it into a Java program.

The blog also shows you how the whole eigenfaces thing works- you basically just need to do SVD / DS-SVD on a matrix of faces-as-vectors

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm more curious about  what happened when I run a shell script which called some java classes and what is $CLASS.